# EXTJS controlled get clipped when browser is resized in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs

My search button and Time frame get clipped when browser is resized in IE8. Anyone got idea? Thanks

Before resize:
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/XHZFjNdbeuJBNeGvJeC7vtMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

After resize:
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/8ea70qzSUIq5uBX9HWbF39MTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

Here are my codes:

```
this.searchPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'search-panel',
    margins: '5 5 5 5',
    layout: 'card',
    activeItem: (this.DEFAULT == 'advanced') ? 1 : 0,
    region:'north',
    split: true,
    frame: true,
    title: i18n('search'),
    collapsible: true,
    titleCollapse: false,
    toolTemplate: searchToolTpl,
    tools:[ searchToggleTool ],
    bodyStyle: 'padding:3px 0 0',
    items: [ this.basicSearchForm, this.advancedSearchForm ],
    monitorResize:true
});


this.on('resize', function(){
    //console.log('search panel resized, manualMode: +this.manualMode);
    if(this.manualMode){
        //resized by a drag of splitter
        //what's the docclass
        var currentDocClass = docclass.selectedDocClass.replace('=','');
        this.createCookie('advHeight'+currentDocClass, this.getHeight(), 30);
        this.manualMode = false;//reset mode
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using?